# Beautifulsoup only returning metadata

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, linkedin-api

Can someone help me understand why beautifulsoup seems to only be returning metadata?

**Here's my code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#create a session
client = requests.Session()

#create url page variables
HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'
CONNECTIONS_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/'
ASPIRING_DATA_SCIENTIEST = 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=Aspiring%20Data%20Scientist&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER'

#get url, soup object and csrf token value
html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
csrf = soup.find('input', dict(name='loginCsrfParam'))['value']

#create login parameters
login_information = {
    'session_key':'youremail',
    'session_password':'yourpassword',
    'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
}

#try and login
try:
    client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information)
    print("Login Successful")
except:
    print("Failed to Login")

#open the html with soup object
# html = client.get(CONNECTIONS_URL).content #opens connections_url
html = client.get(ASPIRING_DATA_SCIENTIEST).content #opens ASPIRING_DATA_SCIENTIEST
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , "lxml")
# print(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'mn-connection-card__name'}))

# print(soup)
print(soup.prettify())
```

**I am trying to parse out some lists on this link:**

https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=Aspiring%20Data%20Scientist&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER

**Here's what the html looks like in that area of the page:**
[image: linkedin search resultsenter image description here]

I've tried a million different ways to parse out even the outer div, but I can't find it. So now, I'm thinking soup is only returning a part of the html.

Comment: Maybe some javascript executes before loading everything, in which case you'll also need to use selenium

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add elements then BS is useless because it can't run JavaScript and you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript. BTW: word `ember` in all IDs in code many means it use JavaScript module `Ember.js`

Comment: @furas thanks so much. that does clear things up and saves me some time chasing rabbits.